# Can I count the number of dates in a column that occur before the minimum date in another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on some ecommerce data where a user's visits and their orders are kept in separate tables. I want find out how many visits a user makes to the site before they make their first purchase.

Right now I can get the order dates for a user and the count of visits before that date, but when I try to narrow it down to just the first visit I keep getting errors.

Is this possible?

My current code for one user is below. It shows a count of days visited before the order date:

```
SELECT ae.USER_KEY,
       ae.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
       min(ae.ORDER_ENTRY_DATE) as min_date,
       COUNT (DISTINCT DATE(ve.VISIT_DATE_TIMESTAMP))  AS VISITS
FROM ORDER_ACTIVITY ae , VISITS ve
WHERE DATE(VISIT_DATE_TIMESTAMP) <= ORDER_ENTRY_DATE
    AND ae.USER_KEY = '35316826'
    AND ve.USER_KEY = ae.USER_KEY
    AND ae.ORDER_ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2022' AND '12/31/2022'
    AND DATE(ve.VISIT_DATE_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN '01/01/2022' AND '12/31/2022'
GROUP BY  ae.USER_KEY,
       ae.ORDER_KEY,
       ae.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
```

and it returns

| USER_KEY | EMPLOYEE_NUMBER | MIN_DATE | VISITS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35,316,826 | 650125 | 2022-07-29 | 3 |
| 35,316,826 | 650125 | 2022-08-11 | 7 |
| 35,316,826 | 650125 | 2022-08-17 | 8 |
| 35,316,826 | 650125 | 2022-08-26 | 9 |
| 35,316,826 | 650125 | 2022-11-14 | 14 |
| 35,316,826 | 650125 | 2022-11-16 | 15 |
| 35,316,826 | 650125 | 2022-11-16 | 15 |
| 35,316,826 | 650125 | 2022-12-23 | 20 |

What I want it to return is just

| USER_KEY | EMPLOYEE_NUMBER | MIN_DATE | VISITS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35,316,826 | 650125 | 2022-07-29 | 3 |

Is this possible?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except those who are arguments to set functions_. I.e. I'd try `GROUP BY ae.USER_KEY, ae.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER`.

Comment: `GROUP BY ae.USER_KEY, ae.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER` would most likely mess up the counts, that are currently partitioned by `ae.ORDER_KEY` too.

Comment: @lemon, grouping by a column that isn't selected rarely ever makes sense. (When I take another look at the question, I realize something is strange.)

Comment: I agree with you, it makes sense only when you are not interested in the partitioning values, as it seems in this case. Problem is that if you remove `ae.ORDER_KEY` from the `WHERE` clause, *probably* you would get the first output row with the sum of all counts into the visit field.

Comment: lemon and Jarlh that is the reason that I have grouped by order key. If I do not have that the row looks like shows the order date of 2022-07-29 and a visits of 20, which is the total number of visits of the user for that time frame.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am using snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is the `GROUP BY` clause is too specific (should not include `ORDER_KEY`), but there are other concerns as well.

One is to stop using the `A,B` join syntax that has been obsolete for *more than 30 years now*. That makes it difficult for us to know which of the `WHERE` conditions in this query belong with the JOIN, which absolutely makes a difference here.

Another issue is there's not a meaningful way in just this data to match up a visit to an order. Thankfully we only care about the first order, so we can work around that. If you wanted to show how many visits led up to each order since the prior order, we call that a "gaps and islands" problem, which can be even more complicated.

```
SELECT o.User_Key, o.Employee_Number, o.Order_Entry_Date, count(DISTINCT v.Visit_Date_Timestamp) As Visits
FROM (
    SELECT oa.USER_KEY,
        oa.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
        oa.Order_Entry_date,
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY oa.User_Key ORDER BY oa.Order_Entry_Date) rn
    FROM Order_Activity oa
) o
INNER JOIN Visits v ON v.USER_KEY = o.USER_KEY
        AND DATE(v.Visit_Date_Timestamp) <= o.Order_Entry_Date
WHERE o.ORDER_ENTRY_DATE >= '20220101' AND o.Order_Entry_Date < '20230101'
    AND o.rn = 1
GROUP BY o.User_Key, o.Employee_Number
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, can add Order By and Limit command.

```
ORDER BY min_date ASC (or ORDER BY visits ASC)
Limit 0, 1
```

Comment: This won't do it. The question is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You do it in 2 steps.
First make a query which gives you the min date which is the basis of the comparison for the second query. You need to design query 1 so that it just outputs the min date.
Then you can test this query and check if the results are satisfactory.

The next step is to put the whole query into parenthesis and use it in the where clause of the second query:

```
select count(ve.VISIT_DATE_TIMESTAMP) 
from VISITS ve 
where ve.VISIT_DATE_TIMESTAMP < (query1) 
group by ve.VISIT_DATE_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the USER_KEY column to join the tables, it is present in both tables:

```
select   ae.USER_KEY
       , ORDER_ENTRY_DATE as min_date,
       max (Visits)
from (

    select   USER_KEY
           , ORDER_ENTRY_DATE
           , firstOrder
        from (
            select  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by USER_KEY order by USER_KEY, ORDER_ENTRY_DATE ) firstOrder  
                    , USER_KEY
                    , ORDER_ENTRY_DATE  
            from #ORDER_ACTIVITY
       )t where t.firstOrder = 1
 ) ae 
 left join (   
    
        select  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by USER_KEY order by USER_KEY ) Visits
              , USER_KEY
              , VISIT_DATE_TIMESTAMP 
        from #VISITS    
 ) ve
on  ve.USER_KEY = ae.USER_KEY
where ae.USER_KEY = '35316826'
group by   ae.USER_KEY
        , ORDER_ENTRY_DATE
```